# angular.js ui-router pass no data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

In my **Ionic app**, I want to pass parameter(s) from one sub-view to another sub-view. When I pass parameters first time, It works as I expected, but my problem is, when I return first sub-view and then go to another sub-view, it goes to that page without parameters. My code is given below:

**index.html (project/www)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
       <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script> 
       <script src="cordova.js"></script>
       <script src="js/app.js"></script>
       <script src="js/main.js"></script>
       <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" >
        <!-- main window -->
        <div>
            <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**route.js (www/js/route.js)**

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $stateProvider
        .state('mainUser', {   // first window
           url: '/mainuser',
           templateUrl: 'templates/mainUser.html',
           controller: 'mainCtrl'
        })
       .state('userDrive', {  // second window
          url: '/user_drive',
          params: {
             driveData: null  // parameter send
          },
          templateUrl: 'templates/user_drive.html',
          controller: 'DriveCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/mainUser');
 });
```

**templates/mainUser.html**

```
 <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content> 
        <ion-content class="padding" style="background-color:#fff;">        
            <input type="date" ng-model="selectData.selectedDate" placeholder="Date">

            <input type="time" ng-model="selectData.selectedTime" placeholder="Time">
         </ion-content>
         <div class="bar bar-footer">
             <div class="button-bar">
                 <a ui-sref="userDrive({ driveData: selectData })" class="button"> Drive </a> 
            </div>
         </div> 
     </ion-side-menu-content>
  </ion-side-menus>
```

Here after click on `Drive` button, it will redirect to `userDrive` sub-view with parameter `driveData` correctly. But where I back to `mainUser` and then change `selectData.selectedDate` and `selectData.selectedTime` and then click again on `Drive` button, it will redirect to `userDrive` sub-view without  `driveData` parameter.

**userDrive** Controller

```
.controller('DriveCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {       
     console.log("DriveCtrl");  // after redirect to this controller second time
                                // it also print no value
                                // seems might be DriveCtrl is not called
     console.log("$stateParams :  ", $stateParams);       
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@leandro-zubrezki is right. To remove cache you can add anywhere in the controller 'DriveCtrl'.

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.afterLeave", function () {
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
});
```

Comment: You should not remove the cache, you should use the view life cycles.

Comment: But why should not we remove the cache? can you tell more

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the view is cached by Ionic, and in that case the controller gets executed only once, so that's why you only see the log the first time.

You need to use ionic view events, here the docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 0):

U can't send object into state param, if u need to send each value separately

Comment: But I sent object into state param, and I think it works